# multiple args function call in map(lambda) function in python

Tags: python, function, syntax, lambda

How would i call this function if the input function is a multiple argument function:

```
def process_list(_func, _list):
    return map( lambda x: process_list(_func, x) if type(x)==list else _func(x), _list )
```

so I can call this `newList = process_list(someFunction, inputList)` if someFunction is a single input function like so:

```
def makeRvtDetailLines(crv):
    detailLine = doc.Create.NewDetailCurve(doc.ActiveView, crv)
    return detailLine
```

However, if i need to call a function that has more than one input ex:

```
def makeRvtDetailLines(crv, _lineStyle):
    detailLine = doc.Create.NewDetailCurve(doc.ActiveView, crv)
    detailLine.LineStyle = _lineStyle
    return detailLine
```

How do i call the `newList = process_list(makeRvtDetailLines, inputList)`? Where do the arguments for the function go? Thank you for all the help.

ps. this is not a Revit question. This is python syntax question.

Comment: Assuming the values for `crv` come from the list, where do the values for `_lineStyle` come from?  Without knowing that, your answer can't be answered properly.

Comment: they could come from another list or in this case a single object

Comment: would that mean that i need to add it to process_list function? process_list(_func, _list, _funcArg)

Answer (score 0):

If `_lineStyle` is a single object, you could use a (very) slightly more complex version of `process_list`:

```
def process_list(_func, _list, arg):
    return map( lambda x: process_list(_func, x, arg) if type(x)==list else _func(x,arg), _list )
```

If `_lineStyle` were a list, assuming it is the same length as the `cdv` list, you could `zip` them together into a single list of (cdv,_lineStyle) pairs, and then modify `process_list` accordingly:

```
def process_list(_func, _list, _argList):
    ziplist = zip( _list, _argsList)
    return map( lambda x: process_list(_func, x[0], x[1]) if type(x[0])==list else _func(x[0], x[1]), ziplist )
```

Comment: yes, can you show me an example of how the zip version would look like?